# Password regex not working

Tags: java, regex

This is my regex for password.

```
((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,20})
```

When I enter `"cdsafcghiufvcdsfvcdsghfcydsgfcghdysufcdus"` more then 20 words its working fine
but when I use `"Akash1AAkash1AAkash1AAkash1AAkash1AAkash1AAkash1AAkash1AAkash1A"` it's not working.

For only lower case or upper case its working fine, but when I use uppercase, numeric and lowercase with maximum length its not working.

I tried almost everything but not succeed.

Comment: Define "not working" (how it works, how it suppose to work and why). Also showing how you are using this regex would be helpful.

Comment: Please define the following: (1) rules of correctness of password in clear English. (2) what does "not working" mean?

Comment: You're seriously setting an *upper* limit to password length? Anyway you missed the ^ and $

Comment: @Dave good point about upper limit, but if OP is using `str.matches(regex)` method then it is testing if `regex` matches entire string so `^` and `$` are redundant.

Comment: @Akash Please explain what do you mean by "working" and "not woking"

Comment: Apart from the redundant outer brackets, it looks OK

Comment: @BalwinderSingh  i am not aware of regex. using above regex, If i enter password "Akash1AAkash1AAkash1AAkash1AAkash1AAkash1AAkash1A" its not showing error message wathr if i enter only "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" its displaying error message. I have to display error on both condition

Comment: @Akash Don't blindly copy any regex without knowing what it is doing. You should state first of all what kind of checks you are looking for the entered password. Based on the checks, you need to define the regex - its not the other way around

Comment: Now, you have two problems.

Regular expressions are not generally useful for non-regular languages (like Passwords). A better (as-in simpler and more maintenance friendly) would be to manually parse the password and simply count the instances.

In 2 years when a bug turns up in your code, you're not going to remember what that RegEx matches, even worse it's going to take forever for someone else to figure out what it does.

Comment: @BalwinderSingh thanks i got it now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Password Regex, now those are fun.

**My submission for you:**

```
^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]).*$
```

**PHP**

```
$re = '/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};\':"\\|,.<>\/?]).*$/mx'; 
$str = 'nonumbersSOITFAILS\nalllowercasesoitfails\nALLUPPERCASESOITFAILS\n111111111111111111111\n1alllowercasesoitfails\nALLUPPERCASESOITFAILS1\n1Aa%\n1%UPPERCASElowercasenumberandspecialcharacter\n1%UPPERCASElowercase spacetoo\n\n\n'; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var re = /^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]).*$/gmx; 
var str = 'nonumbersSOITFAILS\nalllowercasesoitfails\nALLUPPERCASESOITFAILS\n111111111111111111111\n1alllowercasesoitfails\nALLUPPERCASESOITFAILS1\n1Aa%\n1%UPPERCASElowercasenumberandspecialcharacter\n1%UPPERCASElowercase spacetoo\n\n\n';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

**PYTHON**

```
textpop-up
import re
p = re.compile(r'^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};\':"\\|,.<>\/?]).*$', re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)
str = "nonumbersSOITFAILS\nalllowercasesoitfails\nALLUPPERCASESOITFAILS\n111111111111111111111\n1alllowercasesoitfails\nALLUPPERCASESOITFAILS1\n1Aa%\n1%UPPERCASElowercasenumberandspecialcharacter\n1%UPPERCASElowercase spacetoo\n\n\n"

re.findAll(p, str)
```

**[REGEX101](http://regex101.com/r/fV3tP3)**

---

**What it checks for:**

- Minimum of 8 characters
- At least ONE number (0-9)
- At least ONE lowercase letter (a-z)
- At least ONE uppercase letter (A-Z)
- At least ONE special character (!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{};':"\|,.<>/?)

**What it doesn't exclude:**

- Spaces (typically those are allowed in passwords)
- Maximum number of characters (easily changed)
- Probably something I am missing

**What it doesn't check:**

- Middle Numbers or Symbols
- Repeat Characters (Case Insensitive)
- Consecutive Uppercase Letters
- Consecutive Lowercase Letters
- Consecutive Numbers
- Sequential Letters
- Sequential Numbers
- Sequential Symbols
- Dictionary Words
- Syllables

Generally at the minimum level assuming a password matches the conditions and does NOT have a dictionary word in it using this `regex` will insure a median [45-65] score in most password strength testers, and insure a "good" password is provided.

*Back to you question*

"For only lower case or upper case its working fine, but when I use uppercase, numeric and lowercase with maximum length its not working."

```
((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,20})
      ^ the extra `\` makes it invalid for any pattern.
```

With that removed if you have a uppercase and lowercase letter with at least one digit it will match.

Only uppercase or lowercase or digits will NOT match.

Currently it will capture the first 20 characters, but validate unlimited characters.  Use `str.matches(regex)` or the `^` and `$` characters at the beginning and end [ in between the first and last (<-here and here->) respectively] and it will limit matches to between 6 to 20.

As a side note the `regex`you provided does not lead to the results you mentioned so please make sure the `regex` is the EXACT one you are currently working with in the future, as that is the only way you are going to get any usable feedback.